# Maximizing the number of edges of a graph where vertices with the same degree don't share an edge

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a graph with the property that if two vertices have the same degree, they don't share an edge. What is the maximum number of edges the graph can have?

How do you approach this?

A hint would be better than a complete solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: there are at most $n-d$ vertices of degree $d$ for every $d$. For a fixed number of vertices, this means we can use the greedy algorithm, though some  slight adjustments are necessary if $n$ is not a triangular number.